# How can I store a vector in a pandas time series?

Tags: pandas

we store measurement results (flight data) in Pandas data frames.

We would like to be able to have a field "velocity", that is a vector of the
x, y and z components of the velocity. Than it would be easy to do calculations
like calculating the norm of the velocity, or calculating the scalar product
of two velocities and storing the result in a new time series of the data frame.

Is there a way to do this with Pandas?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

fdo = Store() 

df = fdo.getDataFrame(5)

# this works; there are three time series now, that contain the velocity
print df.vx, df.vy, df. vz  

# create a vector of velocity vectors
velocities = np.column_stack((df.vx, df.vy, df.vz))

# this does not work:
df['velocities'] = velocities

print "Start calculation!"

# calculate a vector of the norms of this vector (simple method)
norm1 = np.apply_along_axis(la.norm, 1, velocities)
print np.nansum(norm1)


# calculate a vector of the norms of this vector (fast method)
norm2 = np.sum(np.abs(velocities)**2, axis=-1)**(1./2)
print np.nansum(norm2)
```

Answer (score 3):

use `df.apply` on filtered columns.

```
velocity = ['vx','vy','vz']
norm1 = df[velocity].apply(la.norm, 1)
```

If you are creating numpy arrays out of a pandas dataframe, you are probably doing it the hard way. :-)